# Cannot connect to SQL Server. domain\sqlservername not found. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, error, sql-server, sql

I get the above error on my server manager where SharePoint (2016 on prem) is running: (SQL 2014 and SP 2016 running on same server Windows 2012 R2)

> Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while
>   attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This
>   could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was
>   unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting
>   to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=2;
>   handshake=60067;

Can it be that a SharePoint services in the IIS is started with the wrong account? How do I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can it be that a SharePoint service in the IIS is started with the wrong account?**

**In short,** No.

I suggest performing `IISRESET` then check the Application pools staus that should be stopped in case

- The user password has been changed.
- The domain user has been deleted.

**How do I troubleshoot this?**

The **Connection Timeout expired** error commonly occurs in the following cases:

- An instance of the SQL Server Database Engine is not running.
- The SQL Server Browser service is not running.
- The TCP/IP is disabled.
- The domain user has been deleted.
- The server name was typed incorrectly.
- There are network problems.
- The TCP/IP port for the Database Engine instance is blocked by a firewall.
- The client and server are not configured to use the same network protocol.

Check the detail steps to troubleshoot each cause at

- [Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgment.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/01/30/connection-timeout-expired-pre-login-handshake/)
- [Cannot connect to the SharePoint configuration database.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/22/cannot-connect-to-the-configuration-database/)

Comment: Thank you Mohamed, I went through the steps on the links you gave and it fixed my problem.

Comment: @Heste You are welcome, Glad to hear it helped you :)